# Highcharts stacked area chart with background chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

**What i would like: (not in highcharts)**
[image]

Note the gray backround graph showing the average trend

**What i currently have: (made with highcharts)**
[image]
I managed to implement the stacked area chart, but i would like to add the grey average graph in the background.

Could anyone tell me if and how this is possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this:
http://jsfiddle.net/gaellm/pw4fwdjm/

Comment: and this:http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/34/Dynamic%20Weighted%20Average%20plugin

Comment: You can add new average series in your callback function: http://jsfiddle.net/5cmjh486/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simply adding the "stack" variable to my series, which allows you to build multiple stacks of "stacked area" charts: one for the actual values, one for the average of last week. Thanks to everyone for their input